# Azure make "dist" folder the root

Tags: azure, webdeploy

I have an app I am using WebDeploy to deploy to Azure. I have been able to configure it so that it will not deploy the "src" folder, but how do I configure azure so that it sees the "dist" folder as the root one. Currently, I need to go to http://vsXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/dist/ to view the files. http://vsXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/ just returns "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." I feel like this should be simple, but have not been able to find an answer... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not to deploy content of dist to root of azure?

Comment: Why are you fighting the platform? Just tell webpack to drop the output in the application root instead of `/dist`.

Comment: How do I configure it to drop the contents of the dist folder to the application root? If I could do that, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with Virtual applications and directories.

just change mapping from `wwwroot` to `wwwroot\dist`

See screenshot of how to do this in the azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that only works once. On subsequent deployments it creates a new dist folder in the dist folder, I. E., the the deployed structure becomes /dist/dist/

Comment: @cFin, this means that you have to change your deployment configuration. You need to alter your deployment path to not include /dist

Comment: Thanks. I will try that!